# Physik Instruments' PIPython library

Tags: python, python-3.x, monitoring, raspberry-pi3

I have been struggling in finding a python library today, and I now doubt it to exist. But let's start from the beginning.

I am currently developing a control and detection GUI for an "optofluidics" experimental set-up. Everything is managed using a RPi with Jessie, and the GUI is made with python (PyQT5).

My boss and I ordered a super nice micropositioner from Physik Instruments, because they were saying it was "python programmable". Indeed, they talk about that [on their webpage](https://www.physikinstrumente.com/en/products/motion-control-software/programming/).

The thing is that I cannot find any clue about that library. I tried to install it with `pip`, without any success. While searching about it, I found an "unofficial" version of this named `pi-gcs`. But once installed, I can't import it and use the commands or whatever.

Maybe I am a newbie in package management or repositories, but I would really like to know if people are having the same problem. I mailed my salesperson at the company, hope they will answer. In that case I will detail that here.

Thank you for your help and have a nice christmas!

Comment: "...PI offers PIPython, a collection of Python modules...". That means that they wrote and provide the modules you need, so they should be able to point you to where it is available. Maybe it's a derivative of adafruit's circuitpython

Comment: But the module you found, `pi-gcs` looks like it is what you likely will get.

Comment: Commercial products should imply some kind of commercial support, no? This question will have to have a lot more detail in it, and be changed to describe how a specific module can't be found and the research you did to sort out common "python can't find modules" issues documented everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

On the CD that came with the PI device you should find a directory named PIPython.
Follow the instructions in readme.rst and you can't go wrong. Look in the samples subdir to get a jumpstart on connecting to the device.
If you didn't get the CD, or it's lost, everything can be downloaded from the website, but you have to jump through some hoops to get access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Repo on GitHub at https://github.com/buenohernandez/Ab2 which does contain that library.

It is not a Repo offered by Physik Instruments.

If you don't have that CD ArgentMage is talking about, you may try downloading the Repo as a ZIP file and copy the pipython directory into your project.

Also, the file https://github.com/buenohernandez/Ab2/blob/master/Ablation.py contains the following code

```
try:
    # It tries to import, otherwise installs it
    from pipython import GCSDevice, pitools  # PI Micro library

except ImportError:
    # Warning 
    subprocess.call("installation_error_correction.bat", shell = True)
    module_not_installed = True
```

but sadly the file `installation_error_correction.bat` is not in that Repo.

If this was helpful, consider forking that Repo in case Ab2 deletes it.